# Move values from 1 column to multiple rows organized by a unique identifier MSAccess/SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

`SQL` newbie here. I have a work task that I'm trying to expidite by using `MSAccess/SQL` as they are what I am most familiar with!

I have a spreadsheet with over 6000 unique rows that looks like this:

```
| SampleID | Unique ID | 

|    123     |    ABC    | 

|    124     |    ABC    | 

|    125     |    ABC    | 

|    456     |    DEF    | 

|    457     |    DEF    | 

|    458     |    DEF    | 

|    789     |    GHI    | 

|    790     |    GHI    | 

|    791     |    GHI    |

|    792     |    GHI    |
```

And I'd like to move the values from `SampleID` into individual columns, based on the `UniqueID`, like so:

```
| UniqueID | SampleID1 | SampleID2 | SampleID3 | SampleID4 |

| ABC | 123 | 124 | 125 |  |

| DEF | 456 | 457 | 458 |  |

| GHI | 789 | 790 | 791 | 792 |
```

I'm attempting to do this in SQL/MSAccess using queries on an imported excel table that has over 6000 rows.

I've managed to count the maximum number Samples per a `UniqueID`: 55.

Is there a way to use pivot based grouped by the UniqueID? How should I / how does `MSAccess/SQL` handle null values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot for the same...

```
select *
from 
(
    select SampleID, unique_id
    from table1
) x
pivot
(
    max(unique_id)
    for SampleID in ([Sample1], [Sample3], [Sample3], [Sample4],....)
) p
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply G one! Err, hit enter too soon. I am able to run the first part of the code, but it is giving me an error message when I try to run the PIVOT. I re-wrote the Pivot as follows. Pivot( Max(UniqueID) FOR SampleID in ([Sample1]) )p     and get the following error "Syntax Error in FROM clause"

Comment: sqlfiddle is not working.. else would have given you a demo as well

Comment: I should be more clear, not used to stackoverflow: I tried running it all together and got an error message. I broke the first part into its own query and was able to complete that query. I then added the Pivot text, using only 'for SampleID in ([Sample1]) ' to test it, and received the error.

Comment: "Syntax Error in FROM clause"